# Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) never displays B2c after AcquireTokenAsync()

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

After `AcquireTokenAsync`, I expect MSAL to redirect to a B2C page.  Instead, the screen goes black, and the method never returns.  The debugger shows the program stopped in `AcquireAuthorizationAsync`, on the call `returnedUriReady.Wait()`  What causes this?

EDIT:

My attempt at porting the MSAL example to F#:
https://github.com/bergey/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

The call where it stops is

```
        let ar =
            pca.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, "", UiOptions.SelectAccount, "", null, Authority, Policy)
            |> Async.AwaitTask
            |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

https://github.com/bergey/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/fsharp/FSharp-PCL/WelcomePage.fs#L19
The B2C endpoint is the same as in the [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native), which works as expected.

Comment: Can you post a complete snippet of your code that you are calling? The `Wait()` seems like a possible area that would cause a deadlock on an async Task method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue in an android project. Turns out I forgot to set the manifest of the droid app to access the INTERNET.
Also make sure you have the F# equivalent of

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

in your droid app mainpage.
I believe the same works for IOS

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, `OnActivityResult` was the missing piece, and I feel bad that I never posted that back here.  Thanks for answering.